# Export Flutter application screen to PDF

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

is there any possible way to export flutter app screen/s to PDF, what im looking for is similar to screenshot function, but it should generate PDF rather than a picture.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It wouldn't appear so. The closest is stuff like the [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package that allows you to create a PDF from scratch. That being said, a flutter screen is full of things like complex styles and layouts that a PDF would only really be able to reproduce by rasterizing those elements into images, so the hypothetical package that you are describing would be little more than a glorified image anyway. (Unless your screen is very simple, in which case a from-scratch package should be sufficient for your needs.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use pdf/printing this way:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>> _printKey = GlobalKey();

  void _printScreen() {
    Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
      final doc = pw.Document();

      final image = await WidgetWraper.fromKey(
        key: _printKey,
        pixelRatio: 2.0,
      );

      doc.addPage(pw.Page(
          pageFormat: format,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(
              child: pw.Expanded(
                child: pw.Image(image),
              ),
            );
          }));

      return doc.save();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            RepaintBoundary(
              key: _printKey,
              child:
                  // This is the widget that will be printed.
                  const FlutterLogo(
                size: 300,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.print),
        onPressed: _printScreen,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrapWidget method not found

Comment: It has been changed to `WidgetWrapper`.

Use:
`final image = await WidgetWraper.fromKey(key: _printKey);`

Comment: Thanks! How to make this code create multiple pages? Currently, it creates only one PDF page, it cuts off the top portion. Instead, how do I make it create multiple pages?

Comment: Does this solution only print the one-page screen? Is it possible to print multiple pages?