# Send pdf attached into an email in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, email

I need to send an email with a generated pdf attached.

Right now, I managed to generate pdfs and I can save them to the phone memory, for this I follow this post: [Export Flutter application screen to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563860/export-flutter-application-screen-to-pdf)

But now I want to attach it automatically to and email and send it. With the info in that post it is impossible. Because it leads me to an screen in which I must select the pdf parameters and the pdf name.

Here is the code I used to generate the PDF:

```
void printScreen() {
    Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
      final doc = pw.Document();

      final image = await WidgetWraper.fromKey(
        key: printKey,
        pixelRatio: 2.0,
      );
      doc.addPage(pw.Page(
          pageFormat: format,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(
              child: pw.Expanded(
                child: pw.Image(image),
              ),
            );
          }));
      return doc.save();
    });
  }
```

To send emails I am reading the documentation of the [Flutter Email Sender Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender/example) But I don't know how to generate the PDF automatically with a predefined name, attach it to the email and then, send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are able to generate PDF's and save them in phone memory, now you just need to pass attachments path(where attachment file is saved) in Email constructor like this.
[image]

Complete Send method code.

```
Future<void> send() async {
    final Email email = Email(
      body: _bodyController.text,
      subject: _subjectController.text,
      recipients: [_recipientController.text],
      attachmentPaths: attachments,
      isHTML: isHTML,
    );

    String platformResponse;

    try {
      await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
      platformResponse = 'success';
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      platformResponse = error.toString();
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(platformResponse),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is how to automatically get the path where the pdf is stored once you save it, and add this path to the attachmentsPath argument.

Comment: While saving  a file you can specify the path with filename and use the same. You will be already having the filename.

Comment: How can i do this with this code. I checked it and "doc" dont have a path atribute or something similar

Comment: @xXNukemKS you can combine with package path_provider to set the path where you'll save the pdf file.

Comment: I was trying that, but dont know how to use with my code

Comment: @xXNukemKS The last part in the [pdf package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) show you how to save the pdf file to the path.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about size firebase limiting around 2MB ,

```dart
pdf.addPage(
// Page Ayarları
      pw.MultiPage(
          maxPages: 100,
          theme: pw.ThemeData.withFont(
            base: await PdfGoogleFonts.openSansRegular(),
            bold: await PdfGoogleFonts.openSansBold(),
            icons: await PdfGoogleFonts.materialIcons(), // this line
          ),
          pageFormat: format,
          orientation: pw.PageOrientation.portrait,
          crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          build: (context) {
            return FinalPDF;
          }),
    );
    final data = await pdf.save();
    var base64data = base64Encode(data).toString();

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("mail").doc().set({
      "to": "borakececi@bkscam.com",
      "message": {
        "subject": "*****",
        "html": "This is an <code>HTML</code> email body.",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "filename": "denem.PDF",
            "content": base64data,
            "encoding": "base64",
          }
        ],
      },
    });
   
    return pdf.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to open the built-in mail app, with recipients and attachments pre-populated, you can use [mail_sender](https://pub.dev/packages/mail_sender).

We built this plugin to suit a use-case we had in one of our apps, where from within the app we had to open a native mail app, with the attachments taken from the internal storage.

```
  final _mailSenderPlugin = MailSender();

  _mailSenderPlugin.sendMail(
    recipient: ["john.Doe@gmail.com", "jane.doe@creoit.com"],
    subject: "Leave Application",
    body: "Some lengthy Body text",
    bcc: ["bcc@bcc.com"],
    cc: ["someGuy.promail@gmail.com", "msoffice@gmail.com"],
    attachment: targetFile.path,
  );
```